# Dataframe - Pandas - How ploting same columns of two dataframe for visualising the differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes

```
df1
+-----+-----+-------+
|     | id  | price |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 1   | 1   | 5    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 2   | 2   | 12    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 3   | 3   | 34    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 4   | 4   | 62    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| ... | ... | ...   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 125 | 125 | 90    |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

and

```
df2
+-----+-----+-------+
|     | id  | price |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 1   | 1   | 14    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 2   | 2   | 15    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 3   | 3   | 45    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 4   | 4   | 62    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| ... | ... | ...   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 125 | 125 | 31    |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

I would like to have a plot that shows the both price columns on X axis and sum on the Y axis to see how are the difference between these two dataframes.

I tried the below but does nothing.

```
line1 = df1.plot.line()
line2 = df2.plot.line()
lines = df.plot.line(x=df1['price'], y=df2['price']
```

What is the best way to show the differences between the two patterns of the price in these two dataframes?

I thought of something like this, but if there is a better way to show the differences please mention it.

[image]

Comment: You can merge the DataFrames on ID, then call `df_merged.plot.line()` just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take first column from df1, and second column from df2, there will be no couple of lines, only one. For qualitatively compartion you can use matplotlib in simple way, because it automaticly creates a figure.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': range(0,5), 'col2': sorted([round(random.uniform(100, 2000)) for i in range(0,5)])
                  })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': range(0,5), 'col2': sorted([round(random.uniform(100, 2000)) for i in range(0,5)])
                  })

plt.plot(df1['col2'], label='first')
plt.plot(df2['col2'], label='second')
plt.legend()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

For every arg on x it shows point on df1[col1] and df2[col2]. But with this plot you can not compare it quantitatively.

PS: Here is logic you tried to realize but with seaborn.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='col1')
sns.lineplot(x='col2_x', y='col2_y', data=df3)
```

Result:
[image]

**Optional**

Quantitative comparison.

```
df3['dif'] = abs(df3['col2_x'] - df3['col2_y'])

sns.lineplot(x='col1', y='dif', data=df3)
plt.xticks(df3['col1'])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is really not clear what you mean by "both price columns on X axis and sum on the Y axis"..

Since your ids are the same, you can plot them like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(221)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(125),
'price':np.random.randint(1,10,125)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(125),
'price':np.random.randint(10,20,125)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df1.price,label="df1")
ax.plot(df2.price,label="df2")
ax.legend()
```

[image]